# How do I convert a single column to 3 columns?

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I have large text file which contains data, formatted like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I am trying to convert it to this:

```
1           2             3
4           5             6
7           8             9
10
```

I tried `awk`:

```
'{ if (NR%2) {printf "%40s\n", $0} else {printf "%80s\n", $0} }' file.txt
```

Comment: And what happened with the `awk`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A solution with  `paste`

```
seq 10 | paste - - -
1       2       3
4       5       6
7       8       9
10
```

[`paste`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html) is a Unix standard tool, and the standard guarantees that this works for at least 12 columns.

Comment: How to achieve the requested 40 char column width?

Comment: @RudiC Your answer correctly achieves that purpose. ;) My answer provides a solution to what is stated in the questions' title.

Answer (score 8):

The `columns` tool can do this:

```
$ seq 10 | columns -W 16 -c 3
1     2     3
4     5     6
7     8     9
10
```

`-W 16` is just to set the line width to something small.

`columns` is not a Unix standard tool.
It is part of [GNU AutoGen](https://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/).

Some versions of the more common `column` command may be able to set the number of columns with `-c`, but modern versions seem to have changed its meaning to set the line width by number of characters.

There's also `pr` as suggested by mpez0 in a comment:

```
$ seq 10 | pr -aT3
1           2           3
4           5           6
7           8           9
10
```

`-aT3` is short for `--across --omit-pagination --columns=3`.

`pr` is in coreutils and POSIX, though `-T`/`--omit-pagination` seems to be GNU-specific.

Comment: this seems to work more or less the same way as the better known `column` command. Any reason to pick `columns` over `column` that you might be aware of?

Comment: @iruvar That `column` doesn't seem to have a way to specify number of columns.

Comment: JoL, the `-c` flag exists to specify the number of _display_ columns, which may or may not be different to the "number of columns" that `columns` allows to specify

Comment: @iruvar I'm not sure what you're getting at. The number of display columns is what we want. The actual number displayed may be less than specified if it otherwise would not fit in the set line width, which by default is 79, but other than that I don't see an issue.

Comment: JoL, sorry if I was not clear - my previous comment was in response to your question around the ability to specify number of columns to the `column` command. One could do that using `-c`

Comment: @iruvar Are you talking about `column -c`? That seems to be for setting the line width. According to the manpage: "Output is formatted to a width specified as number of characters." It was originally named `--columns`, but that name was deprecated in favor of `--output-width`. `seq 10 | column -c 3` displays a single column. `column -c 50` seems to limit lines to 50 `c`haracters.

Comment: Ah, they seem to have changed that in a recent version of `column`. The man page for my obsolete version states this : `-c      Output is formatted for a display columns wide.` Anyways, +1

Comment: @iruvar I see online manpages do say that it's for "display columns". Mine comes from the package util-linux in Archlinux. I imagine all linux distros use the same one as mine. I also checked a FreeBSD/PfSense installation and `seq 10 | column -c 3` also displays a single column.

Answer (score 7):

Try like

```
seq 1 10 | awk '{printf "%40s", $0} !(NR%3) {printf "\n"}'
                                       1                                       2                                       3
                                       4                                       5                                       6
                                       7                                       8                                       9
                                      10
```

Comment: `print ""` is briefer and more robust than `printf "\n"` since the former simply uses the value of `ORS` as intended while the latter uses the value you assume `ORS` will have but which it may not (e.g. it might be `\r\n` in some environments). The code has a problem though in  that it won't produce a newline at the end of the text if the input itn's a multiple of 3 lines and so the output isn't a text file per POSIX and so YMMV with what subsequent POSIX tools will do with that output.

Comment: @EdMorton those environments are off topic here though, are there any *nix systems using something other than `\n`? In any case, you could even make the inverse argument: that `printf '\n'` is better because it prints a specific thing explicitly rather than making assumptions that could change based on the OS. I would be very annoyed if the system decided to add a `\r\n` to my file just because I happened to be on Windows or whatever.

Comment: @terdon it's a general comment - anyone can specify ORS to be whatever they want it to be and if your code uses `print ""` instead of `print "\n"` then your code will behave appropriately. I don't use awk on Windows myself but I'd be annoyed if it DIDN'T use `\r\n` as the ORS (and RS) on that platform since that's what other Windows tools I might want to run on the output would be expecting.

Comment: @EdMorton ah, no that was about the site rather than the question: Windows is explicitly off topic here, so we don't bother making things portable for any non-nix environment, so I was just wondering if you knew of a *nix system where the EOL isn't `\n`.

Comment: @terdon "_Windows is explicitly off topic here_" - since when? Cygwin. WSL.

Comment: @terdon again, it was just a general comment on how to make your code work with whatever value of `ORS` is in use at the time. I know there's something in cygwin where you can have RS at least set to `\r\n` depending on some other settings. Something to do with setting BINMODE=3 in gawk and whatever the underlying C implementation passes up to awk IIRC. I code to avoid being impacted by such issues so I don't have to look into them :-).

Comment: @roaima I was thinking of awk running on Windows, neither Cygwin nor WSL, both of which (I am assuming, I don't know for sure) would use `\n` anyway.

Comment: Cygwin with GNU `awk` - `awk 'BEGIN {printf "\n"}' </dev/null | od -c` returns `0000000  \n`, which I must admit surprised me as the Cygwin tools are usually very good at coping with `\n` and `\r\n`.

Answer (score 6):

The tool for this job is `rs` ("reshape"):

```
$ seq 10 | rs 0 3
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
10
```

We can change the column separator to a tab:

```
$ seq 10 | rs -C 0 3
1       2       3
4       5       6
7       8       9
10
```

Or right-align:

```
$ seq 10 | rs -j 0 3
 1   2   3
 4   5   6
 7   8   9
10
```

`rs` is not a Unix standard tool.
It is widely available, however.
It was invented in 4.2BSD, and so is in all of the modern BSDs.
There are ports of it to Linux-based operating systems, such as [to Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/rs), for example.

Comment: An answer with M. Kunze's `rs` should probably also use M. Kunze's `jot`.  (-:

Comment: There's also [column](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html) from BSD 4.3.

Comment: Is `fmt` another option to `rs` ?

Comment: How about the `pr` command, from very early unix? `pr -a --column=3`

Answer (score 4):

This will move the string width alternately between 40, 80, 120 for each line of input:

```
awk '{ m = (NR-1) % 3; i = (m+1) * 40; printf "%*s\n", i, $0 }'
```

Variables:

- `m` - line number modulo 3 (i.e. `0`, `1`, `2` repeating)
- `i` - the indent for the given value of m

In the absence of any other instruction, I've continued to use your own `printf` formatting so that each line of input is formatted as its own line of output, and each will be right-justified in the available space.

If you want three 40-column entries per line as shown in your example, rather than in your code, you could use this (change the `40s` to `-40s` if you want left-justified text):

```
awk '{ printf "%40s", $0 } !(NR % 3) { printf "\n" }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below command , Tested  and Worked fine

command

```
for ((i=0;i<=10;i++)); do awk -v i="$i" 'NR>i && NR<(i+4)' o| perl -pne "s/\n/ /g";echo -e  '\n'; i=$(($i+2)); done
```

output

```
1 2 3 

4 5 6 

7 8 9 

10
```

Comment: On what system did this run?

Comment: on ubuntu  system

Answer (score 0):

Using Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
k=open('filename','r')
p=k.readlines()
for i in range(0,10,3):
    print str(p[i:i+3]).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(",","").replace("\\n","").replace("'","")
```

output

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10
```

Answer (score -2):

Personally, I would prefer the format

```
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9
```

which can be achieved by

```
mkdir temp
cat file | while read FN; do
  touch "temp/$FN"
done
ls temp
```

though you might have to adjust window width to make it three columns.  And you can’t redirect to a file; have to cut-n-paste.  Redirection tells `ls` to do a single column.

Comment: -1 because the OP didn't ask for that format, and if you want it, that's not the way to do it (pipe input to `pr -t3`) anyway.